# Reading JSON-encoded UTF-8 data from PHP service into Ruby app

Tags: php, ruby, json, utf-8, sinatra

My brain hurts, so I need help to solve this issue. I have read about many similar encoding problems but I can't find any info that helps me with this particular issue.

I have a PHP service which reads data from database. It sets the charset to:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con)
```

Basically it then executes a query and loops thru the db items like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  $row->MyField1 = utf8_encode($row->MyField1);
  $row->MyField2 = utf8_encode($row->MyField2);
  ...
  $res[] = $row;
}
```

and ends with:

```
print json_encode($res);
```

I then read the data from Ruby (a sinatra app) with:

```
uri = URI(str)
source = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
src = JSON.parse(source)
src.each do |s|
    # Display s.MyField1 in HTML here....  HTML page is HTML5 and <meta charset="utf-8">
end
```

The problem is that I display strings like:

```
ALLMÃNHETENS ÃKNING
```

where `'Ã'` is some unknown character to me. It should properly be `'Ä'` in the first occurrence and `'Å'` (Swedish A with 'ring diacritic' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic)).

Is it the PHP code that is wrong? Or the Ruby code? If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful? Frankly I don't know where to start chasing bugs.

Comment: What is the character set in the database? There are some hidden pitfalls in there in that some utf8 MySQL collations don't cover all UTF8

Comment: I don't have control over the database so I dont really know?! But if I do `echo "<td> $row->MyField</td>"; etc and return a HTML page (by opening the URL directly from a browser - ie not using Ruby) the data is displayed OK. Its the utf8_encode that I dont seem to be able to decode on the Ruby side. Question is: do I HAVE to use utf8_encode before sending the data by JSON?

Comment: Somehow I believe this web page describes what is happening: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It seems the answer is very accurately described here:

http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html

And the important thing is that my PHP-script must add:

`Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

otherwise the UTF-8 will have their individual bytes interpreted as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 causing exactly the described bevahiour above.

IMPORTANT ADDITION: I also had to remove the utf8_encode() call in the PHP-script since the data already was UTF-8 encoded (or maybe the mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con) did that thing, I don't know).